# Enumerate through a directory and load in txt files and than do some modifications and write back to txt

Tags: r

Lets say i have a directory with .txt files in it like this (note that every file has the same context but different file names):

```
dir('tstdir')
[1]"file1_err1.txt"
[2]"file2_ree1.txt"
[3]"file_test.txt"
```

So to go through this directory i use a for loop (example for readability):

```
for (i in dir('tstdir')) {
    tst<-read.table(paste('tstdir/',i, sep=''),stringsAsFactors=F)
    DO SOME MODIFICATION (Randomizing the data)
    write.table(tst, file = paste('tst',i,sep='')
}
```

So i want to do something per txt file and than write it back to a text file with the names of the loaded files + names of the data frame. ( I know how to randomize the data but not needed for example )

I know i do something wrong with renaming of the data and signing I to the correct place. I thought about an `if` statement but want to see if this can be done without. Unfortunately without success, any help / hints is appreciated

Comment: I don't think literate means what you think it means...

Comment: @LucianoSelzer I think youre right!

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw I think there is just minor typo in your code.. just make sep = '/' and your code should work ...

Comment: @geektrader I see youre point but this is just an example indeed i made a typo over there but this is not affecting my code i changed it in the example though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you want to do? Without an example of the randomising it's hard to say exactly this will work, but it should do...

```
f <- list.files( 'tstdir' , pattern = "*.txt" , full.names = TRUE )

lapply( 1:length(f) , function(x){ 
    dat <- read.table( f[x] , stringsAsFactors = F )

    randomise dat code here

    require( R.utils )
    write.table( dat , file = getAbsolutePath(f[x]) )
    }
)
```

Comment: THanks that worked! I only wonder why i get an error if i change the write table to file = paste(f,x)

Comment: Because `x` is a number from 1 to the number of files in `list.files`, which is a vector of characters. We use `x` it to index which filename from `f` we want to paste as the output filename. You are trying to paste the entire vector of filenames which will result in multiple character vectors being passed as your filename. Try just typing `paste(f,1)` into R - you get more than one filename back. Now try `paste(f[1])` - you get the first filename back.

Comment: I get an error when trying to change the write.table you edited if i try paste(f[x]) i get the error saying no such file or directory.

Comment: try changing it to either `file = f[x]` or if that doesn't work `file = file( f[x] )`. Let me know if either works so I can update the answer for future viewers.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i fixed it a bit different, by setting the `list.files(full.names = FALSE)` and than create the text file by `write.table( dat , file = paste( "test" , f[x] , sep = "." ) , col.names = F, quote = F, row.names = F )`

Comment: Can you paste the output of f[1] here...? If you use `list.files` and then change the working directory it will not work, because you are changing the relative path. I will make an update to the code. Can you check this works as is please?

Comment: IT works perfectly thanks for the good explanation output of `f[x]`
`[1] "tstdir/tst1.txt"
[1] "tstdir/tst2.txt"
[1] "tstdir/tst3.txt"`

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw Great!!